# How can I change the icon of a Console App in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, console-application

I have a .NET 3.1 console application. I use the Visual Studio Code IDE. I build the executable with `dotnet publish` (+ some arguments) from command line. I want the built .exe file to have my custom icon (.ico file).

**What do I need to do to have the built .exe my custom icon?**

- I already read about the [win32icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/win32icon-compiler-option) compiler option but I don't know how to use it
- There are several similar questions on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519844/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-a-console-app-in-visual-studio)) but they're all related to Visual Studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Add you custom icon to the project
- Edit your project file in VS Code and app icon like so

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon>TextTemplate.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

In my example, the file is at project root.
if you place it in a subfolder, you might need to deal with the path accordingly

Comment: I am using same for vs code in mac but its not working... am I missing something?