# How do I change the icon that goes in the task bar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I used to think to change [the icon](http://puu.sh/3hark.jpg) you would simply change [Icon and Manifest](http://puu.sh/3hasN.png) in the properties.

However, changing that doesn't change the icon. How do I change it?

Comment: Do you get that icon when you run the program outside of visual studio as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

icon in `Icon and Manifest` refers to the icon associated with exe file.

Icon in taskbar is your current window icon

EDIT: Also there is a very good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96498/WPF-Integrating-our-application-with-the-Windows-7) about manupulating taskbar in WPF if you are interested

Answer (score 1):

The application icon (the one showing your exe) can be changed in the project properties. Right click on the solution node. Look [here](http://normankosmal.com/wordpress/?p=21) and select the icon you would like to use.
The Form icon can be changed in the form properties. Click on the form and look in the properties for the icon line. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460447/visual-studio-change-app-icon-how)