# namespace name 'icon' could not be found in website asp.net c#

Tags: c#, namespaces

i am working on website on which needed  `icon namespace`.

i am using icons for word,excel  text and many more but when i am add

```
 Icon tempIcon = null;
```

in my web application then below error comes.

```
namespace name `icon` could not be found
```

Have you any idea about namespace for icon in web application asp.net c#?
or any demo??

Comment: yes missing `icon` namespace

Comment: Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460447/visual-studio-change-app-icon-how

Comment: @RameshRajendran its not what u think buddy.. in his web application he wants icons of different files and folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it should work. Try this code:

```
using System.Drawing;
```